# Erro na impressão de array de strings // C++

Tags: array, c++, string, matriz

Estou fazendo uma forca e na impressão da palavra sorteada, está acontecendo um erro em que as palavras são impressas com alguns numeros ou letras não inclusos em seu escopo.

```
const int quant_palavras = 3;
class Forca {

    private : 

    char deposito[quant_palavras][20] {
        "escova",
        "escada",
        "boneca"

        };


    int setSorteio()  {
      int num;
      srand(time(NULL));
      num = rand() % (quant_palavras -1);
      return num;
    }

    void getpalavra_sorteada(int num) {
      for (int i=0; i <= 20; i++) {
        cout << deposito[num][i];
      }
    }

    public :

    void setpalavra_sorteada() {
      int ind = setSorteio();
      getpalavra_sorteada(ind);
      cout << setSorteio();
    } 



};

int main() {

  Forca display;

  display.setpalavra_sorteada();

  return 0;
}
```

Por exemplo, se imprimir a palavra "escada", imprime como : escadab1
boneca : boneca2
escova : escovae0

Acho que o numero é a posiçao da palavra, mas o que seria a letra aleatoria? Como posso fazer para imprimir apenas a palavra?

Agradeço a ajuda desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece porque as strings precisam ser finalizadas com o caracter \0 mas você está imprimindo um array de char no `getpalavra_sorteada`. Mas como vocẽ está usando C++ o melhor é declarar as strings como tipo `string` que é mais adequado. Aqui um exemplo de seu código alterado para usar string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int quant_palavras = 3;
class Forca {

    private : 

    string deposito[quant_palavras] {
        "escova",
        "escada",
        "boneca"

        };


    int setSorteio()  {
      int num;
      srand(time(NULL));
      num = rand() % (quant_palavras -1);
      return num;
    }

    void getpalavra_sorteada(int num) {
        cout << deposito[num];
        cout << "\n";
    }

    public :

    void setpalavra_sorteada() {
      int ind = setSorteio();
      getpalavra_sorteada(ind);
      cout << setSorteio();
    } 



};

int main() {

  Forca display;

  display.setpalavra_sorteada();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: funcionou direitinho. Obrigado!